# seaborn pairplot not working for single graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I get this weird behavior where seaborn will plot diffrent graphs as expected but fails to show data in a single graph.

I am using anaconda3 and Visual Studio (same problem in jupyter).

> seaborn is v0.11.0
> matplotlib is v3.3.1
> anaconda3 is v1.9.12
> python is v3.8.3
> MSC is v.1916 64 bit

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.pairplot(x_vars=["tip"], y_vars=["size"], 
            data=tips)
sns.pairplot(tips)
plt.show()
```

the outputs look like this:

[output for sns.pairplot(x_vars=["tip"], y_vars=["size"],data=tips)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9c1g.png)

[output for sns.pairplot(tips)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAyVL.png)

It seems that the data is clearly there, but is somehow not plottet in the former statement.

edit: It seems to be a library version problem.

these are may library versions:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
attrs                     20.2.0                     py_0
backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2020.7.22                     0
certifi                   2020.6.20                py38_0
cfitsio                   3.470                he774522_6
click                     7.1.2                      py_0
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0
cligj                     0.5.0                    py38_0
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0
curl                      7.67.0               h2a8f88b_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py38_0
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0
expat                     2.2.9                h33f27b4_2
fiona                     1.8.13.post1     py38hd760492_0
freetype                  2.10.2               hd328e21_0
freexl                    1.0.5                hfa6e2cd_0
gdal                      3.0.2            py38hdf43c64_0
geopandas                 0.8.1                      py_0
geos                      3.8.0                h33f27b4_0
geotiff                   1.5.1                h5770a2b_1
hdf4                      4.2.13               h712560f_2
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254
ipykernel                 5.3.4            py38h5ca1d4c_0
ipython                   7.18.1           py38h5ca1d4c_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py38_0
jedi                      0.17.2                   py38_0
joblib                    0.16.0                     py_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py38_0
kealib                    1.4.7                h07cbb95_6
kiwisolver                1.2.0            py38h74a9793_0
krb5                      1.16.4               hc04afaa_0
libboost                  1.67.0               hd9e427e_4
libcurl                   7.67.0               h2a8f88b_0
libgdal                   3.0.2                h1155b67_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libkml                    1.3.0                he5f2a48_4
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h411e497_2
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libpq                     11.2                 h3235a2c_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h33f27b4_0
libspatialite             4.3.0a               h7ffb84d_0
libssh2                   1.9.0                h7a1dbc1_1
libtiff                   4.1.0                h56a325e_0
libxml2                   2.9.10               h464c3ec_1
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h2fa13f4_0
m2w64-expat               2.1.1                         2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gettext             0.19.7                        2
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libiconv            1.14                          6
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
m2w64-xz                  5.2.2                         2
matplotlib                3.3.1                         0
matplotlib-base           3.3.1            py38hba9282a_0
mkl                       2020.2                      256
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.2.0            py38h45dec08_0
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h47e9c7a_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
munch                     2.5.0                      py_0
numpy                     1.19.1           py38h5510c5b_0
numpy-base                1.19.1           py38ha3acd2a_0
olefile                   0.46                       py_0
openjpeg                  2.3.0                h5ec785f_1
openssl                   1.1.1h               he774522_0
pandas                    1.1.1            py38ha925a31_0
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
pcre                      8.44                 ha925a31_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py38_1000
pillow                    7.2.0            py38hcc1f983_0
pip                       20.2.2                   py38_0
postgresql                11.2                 h3235a2c_0
proj                      6.2.1                h9f7ef89_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.7                      py_0
pygments                  2.7.1                      py_0
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0
pyproj                    2.6.1.post1      py38hcfa1391_1
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38ha925a31_4
python                    3.8.5                h5fd99cc_1
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0
pywin32                   227              py38he774522_1
pyzmq                     19.0.2           py38ha925a31_1
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
rtree                     0.9.4            py38h21ff451_1
scikit-learn              0.23.2           py38h47e9c7a_0
scipy                     1.5.0            py38h9439919_0
seaborn                   0.11.0                     py_0
setuptools                49.6.0                   py38_1
shapely                   1.7.1            py38h210f175_0
sip                       4.19.13          py38ha925a31_0
six                       1.15.0                     py_0
sqlite                    3.33.0               h2a8f88b_0
tbb                       2018.0.5             he980bc4_0
threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0
tiledb                    1.6.3                h7b000aa_0
tk                        8.6.10               he774522_0
tornado                   6.0.4            py38he774522_1
traitlets                 5.0.4                      py_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_3
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0
wheel                     0.35.1                     py_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py38_0
xerces-c                  3.2.3                ha925a31_0
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
zeromq                    4.3.2                ha925a31_3
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
zstd                      1.3.7                h508b16e_0
```

Comment: Why are you making a pairplot? why not just a scatterplot? or jointplot?

Comment: Also, what do you want to achieve with pairplot? a grid of 2x2 containing distribution and scatter plot? or just one plot?

Comment: It is working with my environment. Must be an issue in some of the library version.

Comment: the pairplot was used in the script we followed at school, but you are right, with scatterplot it does work indeed. however pairplot has some neat "automatic" functions such as the height argument. I think I can work with that, but still super strange behavior from seaborn...

Comment: @PriteshGohil oh, i forgot to mention that it worked with some students in class today but not with others. Library versions might be the key! sadly its rather time consuming to cross check all librarys with other students. Thanks a lot for your help (:

Comment: @PriteshGohil if you would have one minute to cross check my library list with yours, or post yours to crosscheck myself, that would be super helpful (:

Comment: @cheche see my answer. I have already cross-checked.

Comment: It is [this bug](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2260) (simple workaround provided in the issue), but I still can't think of a case where you'd want a single-axes `pairplot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a bug in either matplotlib `3.3.1` or in seaborn `0.11.0`. I checked with the given environment and giving a blank graph with `sns.pairplot(x_vars=["tip"], y_vars=["size"],data=tips)`.

**Solution**:
Change your matplotlib version to `3.2.1` and seaborn version to `0.10.1`. It worked for me with given versions.

If you are using yml file to create conda environment, use following content in `.yml` file.

```
name: test
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - seaborn=0.10.1
  - matplotlib=3.2.1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it does work with the versions you mentioned. I originally wanted to use it with a pandas dataframe, but no matter how far i downgrade pandas, it won't work with it. but thats a problem for another day (: